# How do I add my jar to Java compilation path?

Tags: java, class, jar

I'm very new to Java programming and I'm trying to add jar to the classpath like this:

```
javac -classpath ~/Downloads/algs4.jar. ThreeSum.java
```

but still I'm getting the exception like:

```
ThreeSum.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
                        StdOut.println(a[i] + " " + a[j] + " " + a[k]);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class ThreeSum
ThreeSum.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
        int[] a = In.readInts(args[0]);
                  ^
  symbol:   variable In
  location: class ThreeSum
ThreeSum.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        ^
  symbol:   class Stopwatch
  location: class ThreeSum
ThreeSum.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Stopwatch
  location: class ThreeSum
ThreeSum.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        StdOut.println("elapsed time = " + timer.elapsedTime());
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class ThreeSum
ThreeSum.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        StdOut.println(cnt);
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class ThreeSum
6 errors
```

I'm trying the programs from [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/)

Comment: The section [Installing the textbook libraries](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/#classpath) explains how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to download this JAR as well: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

They don't have a package structure, so unpack everything in the same directory:

```
jar xvf stdlib.jar
jar xvf algs4.jar
```

Then compile it:

```
javac -classpath . ThreeSum.java
```

Comment: Or, to keep them in jars, `-classpath .:stdlib.jar:algs4.jar` .

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `~/Downloads/algs4.jar.` for that classpath to be `~/Downloads/algs4.jar:.` on Linux or `~/Downloads/algs4.jar;.` on Windows`